# how can i display API result

Tags: api

how can i display the following API result in React?

code i used to fetch api data from url

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { results: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
           fetch('url', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'api-key': 'api-key'  
            }
        })
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }));
    }
```

but this given me error message this line

> TypeError: results.map is not a function Function.renderemployeeTable

i try to replace this line  `this.state = { results: [] };` by the api data below and able to display it using`<h3 class="title">{results.data.Table[0].first_name}{results.Table[0].last_name}</h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
 jsonData:''}}
  fetchJsonData = () => {
      return fetch('http://172.16.0.140:3005/api/v3/users/faq')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonData => {
          return jsonData;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
     componentDidMount() {
        fetchJsonData().then(data => {
          this.setState({
            jsonData: data,
          });
        });
      }

     render() {
        return (
          this.state.jsonData.map((data, i) => {
            return (
    <div>{data.Table[0].id},{data.Table[0].first_name},{data.Table[0].last_name}
    </div>
    )}))}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202860/discussion-on-answer-by-siva-sai-niveditha-how-can-i-display-api-result-in-react).

Answer (score 1):

You need to store in state or send it as a prop and display.

```
<div>{data.Table[0].first_name}</div>
```

Comment: thanks i have prop like this `constructor(props) {
        super(props);`
        this.state = { results: [] };
    }` and return `static renderemployeeTable(results) {
        return (       
            <div class="container-fluid" class="row" fluid={true}>
                { results.map(results =>
                        <div class="col-sm-3" key={results.Employee_Number}>`

Comment: here is what i tried but it gives me codepile.net/pile/gE3kx1Eo

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", {})
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }));
  }
  renderemployeeTable = results => {
    return (
      <div class="container-fluid" class="row" fluid={true}>
        {results.map(results => (
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card our-team">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">{results.id}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{results.employee_name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
              Detail
            </a>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="tabelLabel">-</h1>
        {this.renderemployeeTable(this.state.results)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { jsonData: [] };
  }

  fetchJsonData = () => {
    return fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchJsonData().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        jsonData: data
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.jsonData.map((data, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {data.employee_name},{data.id}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: yes ,i am writing data.employee_name for single dimensional array you write data.data.Table[0].Employee_Number or data.data.Table.Employee_Number actually i forgot your json data

Comment: sorry silva i just tried it with one dimensional in localhost it doesn't work for me. i tried it with this data from postman `[{"Employee_Number":10003,"first_name":"kuku","last_name":"gebre"}]` i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error in this line `> 36 |   return this.state.jsonData.map((data, i) => {`

Comment: Post your json data, I don't know  your json data based on that we will write logic

Comment: Arey, yesterday I post the logic write in that logic use your api and in render function render {data.data.Table[0].first_name} it will work if it is not work render this {data.data.Table.first_name} definitely one will work

Comment: so that means somewhere on my code has a problem did you see my code codepile?

Comment: your answer on a different question

Comment: i think you want to send data from parent child component right